# Ubuntu USB booting when deleted from USB

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb, usb-drive

I recently used an ISO installer and used a USB to install Ubuntu to a laptop. I decided to add a couple different things to the USB so I wanted to delete the recent bootable Ubuntu that was placed on the USB. I cleared and reformatted all partitions on the thumb drive. Unfortunately when i restart my computer the thumb drive still acts as if it has the Ubuntu is still installed. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the MBR is cleared, the drive behaves as bootable. You can do the following:

**Temporary fix:** Change the boot order and remove USB drive from the first position in the list.

**Permanent fix:** Create a new partition table on the disk using GParted.

1. Open GParted.
2. Select your USB drive from the menu on the top right. (Select the correct device or you may end up losing data)
3. Unmount the disk.
4. Go to the device menu and click on New Partition Table. Click on Apply when prompted. (Let the partition table type be msdos. Do not change it.)
5. The entire disk space is now shown as unallocated. Now you need to create at least one partition to use the drive.
6. Right click on the unallocated space and select new.
7. A dialog box opens. Select FAT32 file system and click on Add.
8. Now click on the Apply button. (A green tick mark on the toolbar)

**Note:** If you do not have GParted installed you can open the terminal and type `sudo apt-get install gparted`. (You need a working internet connection to do this)